# Difference Between Cores and Processors

Tags: cpu

I am confused by the difference between "Cores" and "Processors". A lot of the computers are 2-cores, 4-cores. Does this mean that they have one processor with 2 or 4 cores on that single processor?

Also, for intel core i5, it seems that there are 4 CPUs in the task manager, are they referring to 4 core on a processors, or 4 processors with one core each, or 2 cores on 2 processors?

Comment: seems you are not that confused at all.

Comment: The logical cores need to share the internal resources of the physical core providing them (cache etc).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, a [multi-core processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) is a single piece of hardware ("one processor") that provides several cores than can work concurrently.

The **i5** is a single processor that provides either 2 or 4 physical cores depending on model (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_i5)).

Note that some Intel processors (the i5 included) use [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-Threading), a system where a single processor has (for example) 2 *physical* cores, but will provide 4 *logical* cores - allowing the operating system to treat the processor as having more cores than it really does.

Comment: I see, is there any computers that sell multiple processors, multiple-core-on-processor technology?

Comment: @Ngu I think multiple *seperate* processors (with or without multi cores each) are mainly limited to the Server / Data Centre / Cluster type markets. Don't have a citation for that at the moment though, I'll try and find one..

Comment: There are computers that have multiple physical processors, each with multiple cores.  Your Task Manager will show the total number of cores (calling them processors, since a core is just a processor that shares the same physical package with other cores).

Comment: Multiple processors used to be more common in desktops.  Nowadays just having more cores has pretty much replaced that need (other than rare circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a "core" is just a processor that's placed on to the same integrated circuit with other processors. See the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) for further info on multi-core processors.