# What do "processor" and "cpu cores" mean in /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between Cores and Processors](https://superuser.com/questions/168809/difference-between-cores-and-processors)

What do "processor" and "cpu cores" mean here?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 15
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5670  @ 1.80GHz
    stepping    : 13
    cpu MHz     : 1801.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fdiv_bug    : no
    hlt_bug     : no
    f00f_bug    : no
    coma_bug    : no
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 10
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts
    bogomips    : 3591.62
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 15
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5670  @ 1.80GHz
    stepping    : 13
    cpu MHz     : 800.000
    cache size  : 2048 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 2
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 1
    initial apicid  : 1
    fdiv_bug    : no
    hlt_bug     : no
    f00f_bug    : no
    coma_bug    : no
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 10
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts
    bogomips    : 3590.97
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:
```

Comment: This might be related - http://superuser.com/questions/168809/difference-between-cores-and-processors - thou I'm not sure as it's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: Should this be migrated again to unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3):

In this case `processor` is just an identifier (which starts at 0). You have two processors, so they're 0 and 1. `CPU cores` means the number of cores in each physical processor (two here).

Answer (score 0):

It is two processor cores on one die essentially like having a dual processor system in one processor.

The central processing unit (CPU) is the portion of a computer system that carries out the instructions of a computer program, and is the primary element carrying out the computer's functions.