# Windows 7 starter, doesn't it support dual core?

Tags: cpu, windows-7

I bought this netbook:
"ASUS 1015 PEM,
Intel Atom Dual Core N550 1.5GHZ
2GB 250GB 10"

It was Windows 7 Starter installed.
But I read that starter edition doesn't support dual core CPU.
Is it right? If so, I will upgrade to upper version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not true

> PCs with multi-core processors:
>   Windows 7 was designed to work with today's multi-core processors. All 32-bit versions of Windows 7 can support up to 32 processor cores, while 64‑bit versions can support up to 256 processor cores.

But will not recognize more than 1 [Physical processor](https://superuser.com/questions/260788/what-do-processor-and-cpu-cores-mean-in-proc-cpuinfo?tab=active)

> Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, and Home Premium will recognize only one physical processor.

[Source of Information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements)

.

Comment: Physical means a whole, complete CPU. So like.. Intel Skulltrail's 2*775 Core2Q, or a server mobo. Which means ... you don't have to worry about this unless you have such hardware (I doubt that). Only Dell/Alienware/MAC uses server mobo (ultra high-end desktop) with 2 CPUs, but those machines come with Win7 Ultimate by def.

Comment: Thanks Shiki, I made an edit to include a definition link.